# SPListItem Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: splistitem

Am trying to manually pass list item ID as argument in user defined function as Int32 var type. When the list index assigned to splistitem it raise the specified argument error. While debugging it pass a valid integer argument (96, 97, etc). Also the value exist in TargetList.ID. Any idea? TIA.

```
  private void update_contradate(string _trflag, Int32 _listitemID){          

        using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb oWebsiteRoot = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb("/")) // for root list use "/"
            {
                SPList oList = oWebsiteRoot.Lists["TargetList"];

                SPListItem oListItem = oList.Items[_listitemID]; //error 
               ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing your list item ID values which are 1-based integers with the SPListItemCollection index which are 0-based integers.

If you examine the output of the MSDN sample code here:

[SPListItem.ID property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.id.aspx)

you will see SPListItemCollection index doesn't match the list item ID.

In addition, if you look here:
[SPListItemCollection.Item property (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms416789.aspx)

you will find the error you mention and the following remark:

> An item’s index in the collection cannot be obtained by accessing the item’s ID property.

Answer (score 0):

Well it was a wrong method am using instead of :

```
 SPListItem oListItem = oList.GetItemById[_listitemID]; //
```